# Unable to remove my hose pipe ( garden hose ) from the tap ( hose bib )

Tags: faucet

Attachment for hose pipe ( *garden hose* ) was screwed on too tight, now I am unable to unscrew it.

I've tried using a spanner/wrench but it won't budge.

How can I remove it ?

Comment: Show us a picture of what you've got.

Comment: "Hosepipe"? What's that?

Comment: @isherwood , hose pipe = garden hose I knew it from reading the Harry Potter books with my kids years ago.

Answer (score 3):

A spanner like straight jaws will not hold a round fitting well.

You need a pipe wrench or adjustable water pipe pliers with curved jaws.

These pliers adjust to hold the fitting without two much damage and are a basic tool all home owners or some one that lives in a home should have.

Make sure you are turning the correct direction, this may sound silly but after teaching scuba I was amazed how many folks could not turn on or open a valve because they were turning the wrong direction.

To remove the hose turn the fitting counter clockwise , I used to tell my students put your thumb on the top turn right to close or tighten OR turn left to open or loosen. “Righty tighty lefty loosy.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a brass hose fitting and an aluminum fitting and connect them....**THEY WILL FUSE**.  It will be impossible to separate them.

Now, when I connect my hose to an aluminum hose reel fitting, I use Teflon tape to keep the materials apart.

Comment: Aluminum is rare in spigots, being too soft. Most are galvanized steel or stainless.